# What are alternatives to the span-element?

Tags: css, html

say you are working without the `<p>` element in HTML. How would you stylize a simple text with css? What HTML-Tag would you take? I always used `<span>`, but now I saw that span should always be used to group inline-elements (for example `<p>`). And thats not the case in my example.

Thanks,
phpheini

Comment: `<span>` for inline elements. `<p>` to denote a paragraph. `<div>` as a block level element. `<strong>` and `<em>` to bold and italicize text respectively. Unless I have misinterpreted your question?

Comment: But I dont need any paragraphs, inline elements, layers. Say I just want the text to have a specific size and color. And the text is just a text in the body without any p around it.

Comment: So, it's not a paragraph, it's not a block level or an inline element? what is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you should look whether some tag matches semantically. For instance, you might have a text which requires emphasis, in which case `em` is the best choice. Another case is if you have a heading, which you could style with `h1`, ..., `h6`. Always first consider this option!

If there really is no meaning to the text you want to style, or at least, not a meaning supported by css, you can use either `span` (for inline text) or `div` (for block elements).

Comment: This. Very rarely do you need a pure `<span>` or even `<div>`, HTML is rich enough to do the talking in and of itself.

Comment: We grew the bad habit of using too many div and spans. But with the new semantic tags: section, article, aside, header, footer, nav, figure, figcaption, time, mark & main we have a lot of options.

Comment: Use `em` with `font-style:normal;` to not have the text showing up as italic.

Comment: My answer would have been <i> <em> <strong> <small> <b> since they are all inline elements like span.  h1 and div are block elements so they are vastly different.

Answer (score 11):

You're free to use any tag you wish... (Within reason); Just make sure it's semantic.

Just a few you could use:
`<div>` `<em>` `<strong>` `<small>` `<pre>`

Comment: <small> is still good in 2023, just needed something like span and in my case needed to make the text smaller so it makes logical sense too.

Answer (score 1):

`<div>`

Div tags are basically `<span>` tags for block elements instead of inline elements.

Comment: So if I want for example a text to have a specific size I should use a div where my text is inside? Is this really a good way?

Comment: Yep. That's really one of the main uses of this tag.

Comment: Ok, I didnt know that. So just as an example: if you want to have a rainbow text with each letter in a different color and not use javascript, you would do 50 div elements with one letter in each of these layers?

Comment: Yep, though the HTML would probably be a little chaotic.

Comment: This will make all the elements `display` as `block`s, though, and you would have to handle semantic `<div>`s with a bit of CSS. More trouble than it's worth I think...

Comment: w3schools.com  html  and also html5    
They are excellent tutorials.